# Does a portable ILS ground station exist?

Tags: airport, ils

Does anyone know of a good example of a portable ILS ground station?  I mean, it can be used for temporary airfields.

Comment: I don’t think there is such a thing. That’s why the military developed TACAN which can be used for temporary sites or small sites like aircraft carriers.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57267/35166

Comment: @Gerry please don’t post answers in the comments, as there’s no quality control (I.e. your comment can not be downvoted).

Comment: How portable is portable? Is being able to ship it around the world portable enough? How about an aircraft carrier?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[NASA did some research on it in 1986 and published this paper.](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19870004877.pdf) Thales [was contracted to build one that the US Army has ordered](https://www.thalesgroup.com/en/united-states/press-release/us-air-force-orders-thales-deployable-ils-systems) and it made it to [prototype phase](https://www.militaryaerospace.com/rf-analog/article/16714249/thales-to-build-prototype-deployable-instrument-landing-systems-for-worldwide-use). Eventually it was [tested for a while](https://www.afmc.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/1428164/deployable-landing-system-gives-pilots-global-reach/) and appears to have [made it to production and the military ordered more](https://www.militaryaerospace.com/sensors/article/14040229/air-traffic-control-deployable-unimproved-locations).

It goes under the name Deployable – Instrument Landing Systems  (D-ILS). here is a [short two page brochure on the unit](http://tda-armements.com/sites/default/files/asset/document/navigation_-_deployable-ils_17.pdf) which has some good pictures of the whole thing.

[It looks like the units cost around $4.68 million each.](https://www.defense.gov/Newsroom/Contracts/Contract/Article/973062/)

Comment: It makes sense the military would have a field deployable ILS system.

Comment: Note that "deployable" means "can fit in a set of standard shipping containers and only takes five days to set up", not "can drop it at the end of the runway and start landing planes".